# WebClient UploadData gives 400 Bad Request error while posting json data with extended ascii characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webclient, webrequest

I am trying to sync contact with mailchimp. When i have extended ascii characters such as (Johéctíóú Diamond) in contact details it gives  below error.

**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at DealCloud.WinServices.MailChimp.MailChimpHelper.AddListMembersImpl(MailChimpServiceContext context, String listId, List`1 toAdd)**

Below is the code to send json data.

```
 internal virtual string AddListMembersImpl(MailChimpServiceContext context, string listId, List<MailChimpMember> toAdd)
    {
        if (!(toAdd?.Any() ?? false)) return null;

        var uri = string.Format("{0}/batches", context.Url/*, listId*/);

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "apikey " + context.ApiKey);


            //var path = $"lists/{listId}/members";
            var toSer = new { operations = toAdd.Select(x => new { method = "POST", path = $"lists/{listId}/members", body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { email_address = x.Email, status = x.Status, merge_fields = x.MergeFields }) }) };
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toSer, new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });
            var ret = webClient.UploadString(uri, "POST", data);
            var o = JObject.Parse(ret);
            return o["id"]?.ToString();
        }

    }
```

It throws an error on webClient.UploadString method. Is there any alternative approach i should use to resolve this error.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: updated the error message in bold text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely just need to specify UTF8 encoding

```
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

If you don't specify an encoding, then WebClient uses the default for your system, per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx

Presumably that's not agreeing with MailChimp.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to add:
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");

Answer (score 5):

If mailchimp cares to provide a better response, you can get a better idea of the actual error in the debugger output window with:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Response != null)
    { 
        string response = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```